# Python pandas groupby manipulation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Examples of how the df looks like:

```
customer   order_datetime
a          01-03-2017 12:00:00 PM
b          01-04-2017 12:00:00 PM
c          01-07-2017 12:00:00 PM
a          01-08-2017 12:00:00 PM
b          01-09-2017 12:00:00 PM
a          01-11-2017 12:00:00 PM
```

There's 2 thing that I wanted to achieve but I'm still in the learning process, really appreciate any help to guide me in the right direction.

- Create a list of "time between orders" where I can find the min, mean, max
- Find out if "time between order" gets faster/slower, i.e. time between order_3 and order_2 vs time between order_2 and order_1

Comment: This feels like an assignment. Please make an earnest attempt and return back with issues in code.

Answer (score 1):

This example should set you in the right direction for your assignment.

First I'm creating a DataFrame similar to the one you show in the question:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

orders = pd.DataFrame({
    'client': np.random.randint(65, 70, size=15),
    'date': np.random.randint(0, 30, size=15)})

orders.client = orders.client.apply(chr)
orders.date = orders.date.apply(
    pd.to_datetime, unit='d', origin=dt.date(2017, 1, 1), box=False)
# Sorting here is not necessary, just for visualization
orders.sort_values(['client', 'date'], inplace=True)
orders.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
orders.head()

>>>>
  client       date
0      A 2017-01-27
1      A 2017-01-29
2      A 2017-01-30
3      B 2017-01-03
4      B 2017-01-13
```

The key to the solution is in the line `orders.groupby('client').date.apply(pd.Series.sort_values).diff()`.

First we use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the orders using `client` as a key, then we select the `date` column only and sort the dates in each group with [`pd.Series.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), finally we use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) to compute the difference of each record with the following one (here's why the dates in each group must be sorted).

The rest of the code is just to visualize the result, i.e. renaming the Series you obtain and concatenating it with the initial DataFrame.

```
diff_df = pd.concat([
    orders, 
    orders.groupby('client').date.diff().rename('diff')], axis=1)
diff_df.head(10)

>>>>
  client       date    diff
0      A 2017-01-27     NaT
1      A 2017-01-29  2 days
2      A 2017-01-30  1 days
3      B 2017-01-03     NaT
4      B 2017-01-13 10 days
5      B 2017-01-18  5 days
6      B 2017-01-24  6 days
7      C 2017-01-01     NaT
8      C 2017-01-02  1 days
9      C 2017-01-03  1 days
```

Once you have the time differences you can compute all kinds of in-group metrics you need.

First you can try [`pd.Series.describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.describe.html):

```
diff_df.groupby('client').diff.describe()

>>>>
       count              mean                     std               min  \
client                                                                     
A          1   5 days 00:00:00                     NaT   5 days 00:00:00   
B          1  12 days 00:00:00                     NaT  12 days 00:00:00   
C          3   4 days 00:00:00  1 days 17:34:09.189773   2 days 00:00:00   
D          1   4 days 00:00:00                     NaT   4 days 00:00:00   
E          4   5 days 00:00:00  3 days 03:53:40.789838   2 days 00:00:00   

                     25%               50%               75%               max  
client                                                                          
A        5 days 00:00:00   5 days 00:00:00   5 days 00:00:00   5 days 00:00:00  
B       12 days 00:00:00  12 days 00:00:00  12 days 00:00:00  12 days 00:00:00  
C        3 days 12:00:00   5 days 00:00:00   5 days 00:00:00   5 days 00:00:00  
D        4 days 00:00:00   4 days 00:00:00   4 days 00:00:00   4 days 00:00:00  
E        2 days 18:00:00   4 days 12:00:00   6 days 18:00:00   9 days 00:00:00
```

If that is not enough you can define your own [aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

You will need a list of functions if you work on a single Series:

```
metrics = [pd.Series.count, pd.Series.min, pd.Series.max, pd.Series.mean]
diff_df.groupby('client').diff.aggregate(metrics)

>>>>
        count  nunique     min     max    mean
client                                        
A           1        1  5 days  5 days  5 days
B           1        1 12 days 12 days 12 days
C           3        2  2 days  5 days  4 days
D           1        1  4 days  4 days  4 days
E           4        4  2 days  9 days  5 days
```

Or a dictionary of of `{column -> function, column -> function_list}` if you work on the whole DataFrame:

```
metrics = {
    'date': [pd.Series.count, pd.Series.nunique],
    'diff': [pd.Series.min, pd.Series.max, pd.Series.mean],
}
diff_df.groupby('client').aggregate(metrics)

>>>>
          diff                  date        
           min     max    mean count nunique
client                                      
A       5 days  5 days  5 days     2       2
B      12 days 12 days 12 days     2       2
C       2 days  5 days  4 days     4       4
D       4 days  4 days  4 days     2       2
E       2 days  9 days  5 days     5       5
```